# Use ReactJS to get IP inside VPN

Tags: reactjs, ip, vpn

I got some client computers inside a VPN network who, when calling a ReactJS website, should get different data depending on their IP address (static IP from VPN).

So the problem is, I can not use 3rd Party services like ipinfo since they do not have internet access. **My question is, is there a "local" option to do get the IP or some other ID that uniquely identifies the client in the VPN that calls the ReactJS.**
I looked at the webRTC option: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only
but is seems that this is not working (at least not in Fiddler)

I am happy for any clue or ides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactJS is just a User-Interface-JavaScript-Library. So in the end you could use everything the JavaScript-Ecosystem provides you with.
Unfortunately there is no API-call to get the local ip-address with just JavaScript.

The WebRTC-method of obtaining the IP-address was actually considered leaking the IP-adress. For that reason, the IP-address is now being obfuscated when trying to get the local-ip-lookup with POCs like [this](http://net.ipcalf.com/). If you have full control over the computers in question you can explicitly turn off this obfuscation in the chrome browser.

1. Open `chrome://flags`
2. Set `Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC` to false

Another approach could be to host an own "whats-my-ip"-Lookup-Server on the same network. There are a couple of docker-images available in the docker-hub for that purpose. [Like this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/foo0x29a/whatsmyip), [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/eugenmayer/whatsmyip) or [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip).
You could then query the local-network-docker-container instead of an actual third-party-service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. I will check the docker images.

Comment: I found this one to work really nice. https://hub.docker.com/r/ivanmihov/whatsmyip